# Escape strings to \uNNNN/\xNN form

Tags: javascript

how can i escape string to \uNNNN/\xNN form like 'test test' -> 'test\x20test' in java script

```js
escapefunction('test test');  // "test\\x20test"
console.log(escapefunction('test test'));  // test\x20test
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Split, join would be a way